# Использование wget python

Tags: python-3.x, wget

Я создаю приложение для автоматического скачивания файла с ЯД.Официальное`API` решил не использовать, а прибегнуть к сервису для `выпрямления ссылок`. Использую код вида

```
import wget
down = https://getfile.dokpub.com/yandex/get/https://yadi.sk/d/Pyn1bcbBVa1B5A
wget.download(down)
```

при вызове функции `wget.download(down)`
Вызывается исключение: `IndexError: list index out of range`. Почему это происходит и как это исправить насчет работоспособности ссылки можете проверить сами.

Comment: скорее всего из-за второго https://

Comment: второй https необходим так как сервис тогда не выпрямляет ссылку на файл

Comment: ну вот он там бьёт и очевидно ломается https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/python-wget/src/default/wget.py

Answer (score 0):

После нескольких тестов было замечено что создаются файлы вида `Pyn1bcbBVa1B5A0x_c5w4.tmp`и при реформате их в `zip` оказываются полностью рабочим архивом.